# Meteor + Apollo Subscription: Websocket connection closed

Tags: meteor, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I'm using meteor and trying to make Apollo Subscriptions to work, but I'm getting

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:3000/sockjs/401/m892wugm/websocket' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response` in the client.

I followed apollographql.com guide for [Server Configuration](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-subscriptions/meteor.html) and [Client Configuration](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/subscriptions.html#subscriptions-client) but I'm not quite sure how to connection the client to the server yet.

In the client, I'm using **ApolloClient** and **ApolloLink** to pass the **Meteor auth** to GraphQL.

Here's the code:

**Client**

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { InMemoryCache } from   'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link'

const httpLink = new createHttpLink()
const authLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  operation.setContext(() => ({
    headers: { 'meteor-login-token': Accounts._storedLoginToken() },
  }))
  return forward(operation)
})

export default ApolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})
```

**Server**

```
createApolloServer({
  schema,
  tracing: true,
  cacheControl: true,
})

new SubscriptionServer({
  schema,
  execute,
  subscribe,
}, {
  server: WebApp.httpServer,
  path: '/subscriptions',
})
```

**Package.json (not everything, of course)**

```
Meteor 1.6.1.1
...
"apollo-client": "^2.2.5",
"apollo-link": "^1.2.1",
"apollo-link-context": "^1.0.7",
"apollo-link-http": "^1.5.3",
"apollo-link-ws": "^1.0.8",
"subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.9",
...
```

I read somewhere that passing **noServer**: true to the SubscriptionServer() resolve the conflict. The error indeed goes away, but the subscription doesnt seem to work either.

**And yes, I have followed the [Meteor Integration](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/meteor.html#Client-1) guide from apollographql, but the info there is outdated and does not work.**

Comment: I'm seeing a similar problem. Did you ever figure out this issue?